# Windows Server 2003 - Are ODBC Data Sources set per-user?

Tags: odbc, windows-server-2003-r2

When I'm logged into our Windows Server 2003 server, I don't see any ODBC Data Sources, but when a different user logs in (who doesn't have Administrative rights), they have a big list of ODBC Data Sources.

Are ODBC Data Sources set on a per-user basis? How come the Administrator can't see user's ODBC Data Sources?

EDIT: Thanks for the replies. The Answer was staring me in the face :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set ODBC sources by either System or User. Check the ODBC connection definitions under Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> ODBC. You'll see seperate tabs for 'User' and 'System' DSNs.

You can check out a users ODBC connections in their registry hive under SOFTWARE\ODBC

Answer (score 1):

ODBC data sources can be defined per-user or per-system.

When you launch the ODBC manager, you'll see "System DSNs" and "User DSNs".

System DSNs are defined for the whole system, so any user and system services can use them (but only an Administrator can define and manage them).

User DSNs are defined per-user, any user can create them, but only their owner can use and manage them.

Comment: Argh, the infamous DSN/DNS mistake... thanks, Graeme :-)

Comment: No problem. Muscle memory is a real bummer sometimes. ;-)